# Any alternative solution to Avoid "for loops" while getting items from List using Java 8 stream particularly in my case?

Tags: java, cassandra

```
public void delete(String date) {
    List<List<String>> keySets = kva.getDistinctPartitionKeys(
            Dto.class, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    List<Pair<String, String>> pairs = keySets
            .stream()
            .sorted((k1, k2) -> Utils.compareMinitues(k1.get(1),
                    k2.get(1)))
            .map(keySet -> Pair.of(keySet.get(0), keySet.get(1)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    int index = pairs.size() - 1;
    Pair<String, String> pair = pairs.get(index);

    if (pairs.size() >= 0 || !pairs.isEmpty()) {
        for (; index >= 0; index--) {
            if (pairs.get(index).getValue().contains(date)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        List<Pair<String, String>> deletePairList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (; index >= 0; index--) {
            pair = pairs.get(index);
            deletePairList.add(pair);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < deletePairList.size(); i++) {
            pair = deletePairList.get(i);
            final SearchConditions sc =
                    new SearchConditions(SearchCondition.eq(Dto.Keys.SUBSYS_TIPE_CD, pair.getLeft()),
                            SearchCondition.eq(Dto.Keys.SAVED_TIME_MINUTE, pair.getRight()));
            List<Dto> dtos = kva.search(sc, Dto.class);
            kva.delete(dtos);
        }
    }

}
```

}

As you can see above code I'm having a `List<Pair<String, String>` both Pair objects are of String type..i want to search by 2nd pair object which is String type date,
after i get the pair of user inputted date from list, i want to delete all the previous pair records from that date & want to keep other remaining records.

In my code the list is sorted & can consists multiple records from same date so i traversed list from bottom & searched for the latest date index..after i get the latest searched date index, I'm adding all of its previous records till "0"th index in a new list(deletePairList) & deleting that list.

The Above code & logic is working perfectly as per my requirement but..I've used 3 for loops which is costly i think & not efficient way.

Really appreciate if someone can suggest me better way using Java 8 stream().filter() or IntStream or any other better solution to get the same Result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything to do with streams and anything to do with indexes don't mix.  Stick with the old-style code.

Comment: @ Louis Wasserman : My objective is to get the cost effective solution, i only got the solution on it with indexes..I'll appreciate if you can suggest me better way to deal this problem without using indexes.